# calculate report failed redis keys empty but exists

Tags: php, redis, lumen

I have a function like this using Laravel lumen framework:

```
// Define sample payment transactions
$transactions = [
  ['transaction_id' => 1, 'amount' => 100, 'status' => 'success', 'payment_method' => 'credit_card', 'timestamp' => time()],
  ['transaction_id' => 2, 'amount' => 150, 'status' => 'success', 'payment_method' => 'paypal', 'timestamp' => time()],
  ['transaction_id' => 3, 'amount' => 200, 'status' => 'failed', 'payment_method' => 'credit_card', 'timestamp' => time()],
  ['transaction_id' => 4, 'amount' => 200, 'status' => 'failed', 'payment_method' => 'credit_card', 'timestamp' => time()],
  ['transaction_id' => 5, 'amount' => 200, 'status' => 'failed', 'payment_method' => 'credit_card', 'timestamp' => time()],
];

// Store sample transactions in Redis
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
  try {
    Redis::hmset("transaction:{$transaction['transaction_id']}", $transaction);
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Log any errors or exceptions
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::error("Error storing transaction in Redis: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
}


// Generate report by payment method
// Define payment methods
$paymentMethods = ['credit_card', 'paypal', 'bank_transfer']; // Add more payment methods as needed

// Initialize report array
$report = [];

// Calculate total amount and count for each payment method
foreach ($paymentMethods as $method) {
  $transactions = Redis::keys("transaction:*:payment_method:{$method}"); // on this keys why show an empty 

  // Check if $transactions is an array before counting
  $totalAmount = 0;
  $totalCount = count($transactions);

  foreach ($transactions as $key) {
    $data = Redis::hgetall($key);
    $totalAmount += $data['amount'];
  }


  $report[] = [
    'payment_method' => $method,
    'total_amount' => $totalAmount,
    'total_count' => $totalCount,
  ];
}

return response()->json($report);
```

I need to handle much of the data and store the data to Redis so I can consume the cache data.
My goal is I just want to calculate the report by payment method but when I used **Redis::keys("transaction:*:payment_method:{$method}")** the value show an empty.

Comment: try to append payment method to the key (method hmset)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to maintain an INDEX yourself.
After each insert, you can run

```
sadd payment_method:{$transaction['payment_method']} {$transaction['id']}
```

and if you need get stat, run

```
smembers payment_method:{$payment_method}
```

to get all keys
and run

```
hgetall keys
```

to get all related transaction